# How do we fetch sitemaps from google search console for a site with has domain(sc-domain) property?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using the dotnet-client for search console api. When I call sites api, i get a list of sites and one them is something like sc-domain:example.com. When i use it to call the sitemaps api, i get the error saying that it's not a valid site url.

So what is the correct syntax to handle the sc-domain:example.com syntax sites?

```
var sites = await service.Sites.List().ExecuteAsync();
foreach(var site in sites.SiteEntry)
service.Sitemaps.List(site.SiteUrl).ExecuteAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems the sitemap endpoint does not support the domain property params.

Given your domain is 'mycompany.com', you were using `sc-domain:mycompany.com` as siteUrl, to fix this issue just follow the steps below:

- Go to https://search.google.com/search-console
- Click in the properties dropdown
- Click in "Add property"
- Select the "Select property type" as "URL Prefix"
- Fill the URL with "https://mycompany.com"

The domain will be automatically verified because the `sc-domain:mycompany.com` is already verified.

In your code you should use "https://mycompany.com" instead of "sc-domain:mycompany.com" and the sitemaps endpoint will work well.